# SQL Optimization, Nested Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

What would be better way to implement such view so that the query doesn't take too long.

```
select * from table
where ID in (
SELECT ID FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
)
```

Our server will need to run this every 10 mins. I thought of Indexing ID but wasn't sure if that would be the right way to go.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? You've tagged both. I'm assuming the former since that's where the performance problems seem t be...

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `JOIN` performs better as it is explained below. I wanted to add that you *definitively* need an index on `ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t.* from table t
join
(
SELECT ID FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
) a
on a.id=t.id
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! With our DBA gone and me left in charge, you all came to the rescue!